# R generating new data.table slowdown

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table listing intervals during which patients were exposed and the start and stop times during which they were observed for exposures. Exposure happens over intervals during observation. I want to generate the opposite intervals in which the patients were unexposed.

The data I have are formatted like the following:

```
library(data.table)
DT = fread("
id t0  t  s tn
1   1  2  4 15
1   1  6  7 15
1   1 10 12 15
2   4  5  7 44
2   4  9 15 44
2   4 17 35 44")
```

t0 is the start time of observation, t is the start of exposure, s is the end of exposure, and tn is the end of observation. An example might be exposure to extreme UV in workers. ID 1 begins work in the first month of 2000, then in the second month is exposed to extreme UV in normal working conditions, and this stops in the fourth month as cloud cover persisted for 2 months. The "s" ending time represents the clouds in the fourth month. They persist for 2 months in "safe" conditions until the 6th month when UV rises again for another 2 months. And so on...

I want to generate the intervals in which the exposure did *not* happen based on these data. That is, when the participant is in the "safe" conditions. The example output would be:

```
id  t  s
1   1  2
1   4  6
1   7 10
1  12 15
2   4  5
2   7  9
2  15 17
2  35 44
```

The first step I have is to set a data.table in the following manner:

```
nonexp <- DT[, .(t=c(t0[1], s), s=c(t, tn[1])), by=id]
```

but in my dataset of over 140,000 events, this is running VERY slow. I am working in a remote compute environment that is heavily moderated, so I cannot tell whether the system is running slowly or my code is bad.

Is this code obviously suboptimal in some important ways? Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: I'm finding it quite hard to understand the logic of your question.  Could you have a go at editing it to improve clarity?

Comment: @dww I tried to explain the data source with an example. Aside from that I cannot tell what is confusing based on your feedback.

Comment: OK that helps, I think I get it now (although I think you could still improve the wording somewhat).

Comment: What're the conditions used to determine if a given interval is "safe"? I do not see that in the code. A quick and easy way would be to first add a new column to determine if a given interval is safe and then filter by safe intervals and id.

Comment: @Gautam any interval between `t0` and `tn` that's not covered between `t` and `s`. All the intervals listed are "unsafe", I need to generate their opposites/inverses as the "safe" ones.

Comment: I just tested `y = x[, .(start = c(t0[1], s), stop = c(t, tn[.N])), by=id]` on a data.table of 50 million rows, and it takes just a couple of seconds on my machine.

Comment: If you only want the safe intervals, you'll have one vector per id. You can use `setdiff` over the entire range `t0:tn` for a given id and the unsafe periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd store the data so that time variables are not split over multiple columns:

```
# bounds table
bdDT = melt(unique(DT[, .(id, t0, tn)]), id = "id", value.name = "t")
bdDT[variable == "t0", status := "safe"]
bdDT[variable == "tn", status := "end"]
bdDT[, variable := NULL ]

# core table
treatDT = melt(DT, id="id", value.name = "t", meas = c("t", "s"))
treatDT[variable == "t", status := "treated"]
treatDT[variable == "s", status := "safe"]
treatDT[, variable := NULL ]

# stack
res = unique(rbind(treatDT, bdDT), by=c("id", "t"))
setkey(res, id, t)
```

The data now looks like

```
    id  t  status
 1:  1  1    safe
 2:  1  2 treated
 3:  1  4    safe
 4:  1  6 treated
 5:  1  7    safe
 6:  1 10 treated
 7:  1 12    safe
 8:  1 15     end
 9:  2  4    safe
10:  2  5 treated
11:  2  7    safe
12:  2  9 treated
13:  2 15    safe
14:  2 17 treated
15:  2 35    safe
16:  2 44     end
```

From here, if you want to browse safe spells, there's...

```
> res[status == "safe"][res[status != "safe"], on=.(id, t), roll=TRUE, 
  .(id, start = x.t, end = i.t)
]

   id start end
1:  1     1   2
2:  1     4   6
3:  1     7  10
4:  1    12  15
5:  2     4   5
6:  2     7   9
7:  2    15  17
8:  2    35  44
```

Note: if some treatment goes all the way to `tn`, it will not show up here as a zero-length spell.

---

Alternately, if you have enough RAM, a cleaner way is to expand the data...

```
idDT = unique(DT[, .(id, start = t0, end = tn)], by="id")
fullDT = idDT[, .(t = start:end), by=id]

fullDT[, status := "safe"]
fullDT[DT, on=.(id, t >= t, t < s), status := "treated"]
```

From there, you can collapse to spells for easier browsing

```
fullDT[, 
  .(start = first(t), end = last(t))
, by=.(id, status, g = rleid(id, status))][, !"g"][,
  end := replace(end + 1L, .N, last(end))
, by=id][]

    id  status start end
 1:  1    safe     1   2
 2:  1 treated     2   4
 3:  1    safe     4   6
 4:  1 treated     6   7
 5:  1    safe     7  10
 6:  1 treated    10  12
 7:  1    safe    12  15
 8:  2    safe     4   5
 9:  2 treated     5   7
10:  2    safe     7   9
11:  2 treated     9  15
12:  2    safe    15  17
13:  2 treated    17  35
14:  2    safe    35  44
```

The `replace` step is needed because the OP writes overlapping end and start dates.

Comment: Thanks for these elegant and efficient alternatives. They seem to work nicely. @dww's point about my code running decently also seems to suggest that the apparent "slowness" may also just be the terminal server being bogged down. As I mentioned I cannot view other users' activity or memory usage, so stuck in a bit of a cart-horse paradox.